# iText Barcode128 - illegal characters for barcode

Tags: java, itext, code128

I'm attempting to generate a `barcode128` in `iText`, with the following code:

```
Barcode128 shipBarCode = new Barcode128();
shipBarCode.setCode(getOrder().getPartnerPurchaseOrderNumber());
shipBarCode.setBarHeight(40f);

PdfPCell barCodeCell = new PdfPCell();
barCodeCell.addElement(
    shipBarCode.createImageWithBarcode(cb, BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.BLACK)
);
barCodeCell.setFixedHeight(55f);
barCodeCell.setPaddingRight(15f);
barCodeCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
barCodeCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

table.addCell(barCodeCell);
```

but I'm receiving the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: There are illegal characters for barcode 128 in '509868_1_2_1'.
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.Barcode128.getRawText(Barcode128.java:518)
at com.stuhrling.orderprocessing.partner.shopnbc.ShopNBCPackingSlip.getOrderInfoTable(ShopNBCPackingSlip.java:142)
at com.stuhrling.orderprocessing.partner.shopnbc.ShopNBCPackingSlip.getPackingSlipElement(ShopNBCPackingSlip.java:610)
at com.stuhrling.orderprocessing.label.PDFComboLabel.packingSlipCell(PDFComboLabel.java:131)
at com.stuhrling.orderprocessing.label.PDFComboLabel.generateLabel(PDFComboLabel.java:87)
at com.stuhrling.orderprocessing.OrderService.generatePackingSlip(OrderService.java:731)
at com.stuhrling.orderprocessing.PackingSlipListener.handleMessage(PackingSlipListener.java:60)
at com.stuhrling.orderprocessing.messaging.MessageListener.run(MessageListener.java:76)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Apparently, `code 128` does not read underscores.. or maybe it's a bug in `iText`?

Does anyone know of a workaround for this in `iText`?

**Update:**

---

Looks like it bugs out even *without* the underscore, so now I'm even more stumped... :(

I wonder what's wrong with my code?

BTW, It only happens if I have only numbers; if I add a letter the problem disappears.

Comment: Barcode128 works correctly since forever. You may have some unprintable chars in the string. Try to generate the PDF with some literals directly.

Comment: Did that, with the same results.

Comment: Hi. I don't have enough knowledge regarding `iText` as for giving ideas for another title, but I would suggest changing it to a more suggestive one; otherwise there's the possibility of your question getting downvoted by someone.
EDIT: just after I made this comment the title was edited. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm right about this, but I thought it might be a bug. After stepping through itext's **Barcode128.java** I changed this (line 442):

```
if (currentCode != codeSet.getStartSymbol())
        throw new RuntimeException(MessageLocalization.getComposedMessage("there.are.illegal.characters.for.barcode.128.in.1", text));
```

to this:

```
if (codeSet != Barcode128CodeSet.AUTO && currentCode != codeSet.getStartSymbol()) 
        throw new RuntimeException(MessageLocalization.getComposedMessage("there.are.illegal.characters.for.barcode.128.in.1", text));
```

The itext version is **5.5.4**. If there is anyone out there familiar with the code, perhaps you can tell me whether this truly is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think itextpdf 5.5.4 bug.
When I upgraded to 5.5.12, it is resolved.